# Setting up existing site on dev server, how do I make "/some folder/file" direct to the application folder instead of the server root?

Tags: iis, path, coldfusion, root

I have been given a zip file of an existing site to make some changes. All of the paths within the site use a path structure that starts with "/". In an environment where the site is mapped to a domain name, that is fine. However, when I drop the site into a folder on my development server which i reference like:
    "//[myserver]/[thissite]/[index.cfm]"

I get constant 500 errors because every include or location reference looks at:
    "//myserver/file"

This is probably a really simple issue to resolve but in my 20 years of developing sites, I have never had to deal with it as I always use links relative to the file instead of to the site root.

My first inclination was to just replace the links with relative links but with more than 800, it is not only impractical, but additionally, I can't change every page in the site. I am just supposed to fix the things that are broken.

My development server is running ColdFusion 11 integrated with IIS so the files are located in the "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\siteFolder"

I have tried:
Setting application mapping in an application.cfc file:

```
this.mappings[ "/" ] = expandPath("/siteFolder");    
this.mappings[ "/" ] = expandPath("/siteFolder/");
this.mappings[ "/" ] = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath());
this.mappings[ "/" ] = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) & "/";
```

Tried setting up a new site in IIS:

Creating another website in IIS and binding it to siteFolder.myserver and myserver.siteFolder both of which resulted in DNS errors
I have also converted the folder to an application in IIS and still no difference.

I am thinking there might be a way to do it through url rewriting, but before spending more time on something that may not work, I thought I was ask for a little help to see if I was on the right track.

Comment: You might be able to get away with using Commandbox and avoiding the whole setup process, depending on how old the app is. Commandbox allows you to run en embedded server from the command line and will launch a new instance of your app. It ships with the latest release of Lucee, but there is a way for you to specify your own version of CF. Check it out: https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox

Comment: Thanks for the input but it looks like it would introduce a whole new set of variables into the equation. I was really hoping that it would be something as simple as an IIS setting or a this.mapping variable in the cfapplication.cfc. Looking that the code, I have absolutely no idea how the application has worked in its current state.

Comment: Mappings won’t help you here because they are specifically for mapping paths in your server side code, when creating CFCs and calling modules. You might want to look into urlrewrite filters in IIS, which will take existing urls and rewrite them to something else.

Comment: Set up a new site in IIS, add a binding to http://yoursite.local and add that to your hosts file.

Comment: I assumed you have knowledge of setting up a CF site in IIS, but if you don't, it's not as trivial as one might hope. Assuming you have CF installed, and during the install you told it to use IIS, then you're part of the way there. Search for "setting up ColdFusion on IIS" and you should find some articles that will help. Alternatively for development, you can use the CF built in web server (tomcat) and that might make things a bit easier.

Comment: @Gary Stanton - That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: Hey, glad that worked out for you. Worth noting though ACF comes with the 'Web server configuration' tool that will add those virtual directories (CFIDE, Jakarta) for you as well as some other bits and pieces you might have missed by doing it manually. I'm not sure if things have changed in 2018, but my usual process is to add the site to IIS, then to run the configuration tool to tell IIS that it's a CF site. Lucee just handles all this without any messing about.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your current process is to drop applications into subfolders of a single CF website on your IIS server. This will generally work as the presence of an `Application.cfc` in the subfolder will designate it as a new application with its own scopes, etc. As you've discovered however, it will mess with any absolute paths you may have in the templates.

Your best bet is to set this up as a new site in IIS. You need to set a binding up for it (I tend to use `sitename.local`) and you'll need to add that to your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) with the following format:

```
127.0.0.1    yoursite.local
```

Once this is done, you'll want to let IIS know that this is intended to be a ColdFusion application. ACF comes with the **Web Server Configuration** tool which should be in your start menu. (If not, you can find it in `\runtime\bin\wsconfig.exe`).

This will let you select which IIS sites are expected to use CFML and will set up the IIS connectors properly.